# What's Neo saying?

Tags: words, meaning, transcription

In "The Matrix Revolutions", at the final showdown, there's a brief exchange:

> Smith: アンダーソン君　お帰り
>   Smith: 会いたかった
>   Neo:　今夜が最後だ

That's what the subtitles say, anyway.  The dub is almost identical for Smith (he adds "君に" at the start of the second line), but Neo says something different that I don't recognize.  It sounds like: "今夜 けりがつく" (??).

I'm assuming that what Neo says is equivalent in meaning to "最後だ", but I don't know anything like that that sounds like what he says.

(If this doesn't sound familiar to anyone, I can try recording the audio.)

Comment: Have you looked けりがつく up in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, and it wasn't in my Kodansha, nor my 大辞林, and so I figured I mustn't have heard it correctly.

Comment: Darius: What dictionary do you recommend?  You sound like you're suggesting that you have a dictionary which contains this word.

Comment: It is in 大辞泉 (which can be searched along with 大辞林 on kotobank.jp), and it is also in 英辞郎 (which can be searched using www.alc.co.jp), as well as in EDICT (which can be searched using jisho.org, but honestly I wouldn't recommend using EDICT for anything :-)

Comment: Is there any way for us to give a certain answer to this without having the source audio?

Comment: @ssb Personally, I think an answer describing けりがつく／けりをつける would be fine without checking the audio.  The OP is asking if there's something equivalent in meaning to "最後だ" that sounds like "けりがつく", and the answer seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 6):

In classical Japanese, けり (from 来あり) had the basic meaning of "came to think of/realize...". Over time, people observed that this word frequently appeared at the end of lines in their writing, and combined with the conclusive nuance of the word itself, began to use it in the transferred figurative meaning of "the ending".

Reference [大辞泉](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%91%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8C%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8F-491130):

> **けりが付・く**
>
> 物事の結末がつく。決着する。「喧嘩両成敗ということで―・いた」

Answer (score 4):

I have a DVD but I think it's a different version because its subtitles are:

> Smith: お帰り　アンダーソン君　待ちわびたよ　なかなか壮観だろ？　
>   Neo: 今夜　終わる

and its audio goes:

> Smith: アンダーソン君　お帰り　君に会いたかった　なかなか壮観なもんだろ？
>   Neo: 今夜けりがつく

(not sure if this answers your question though...)

Answer (score 1):

http://gogen-allguide.com/ke/keri.html

-keri is a conjugational suffix in classical japanese for the past tense.
http://www.classical-japanese.net/Grammar/past.html

Your contextual intuition was correct for the meaning of the phrase.